# Why does my code not output the correct number of islands in the Number of Islands problem using C?

Tags: c

I am trying to do the Number of Islands problem where the user needs to input 1s and 0s to a 2D matrix and we count the number of interconnected 1s that form 'islands'. I have been having problems with my code. For some strange reason, it works for some matrices but not all, and I do not know what is wrong with it.

```
//starts the search for neighbors
    for(i=0; i<n;i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] == 1){
                objects++;
                neighborCheck(n, m,i, j, arr);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the part where we start searching for neighbors, fairly easy to understand...

```
int neighborCheck(int n, int m, int i, int j, int arr[n][m]){
    if(i < 0 || i > n || j < 0 || j > m || arr[i][j] == 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        arr[i][j] = 0;
        neighborCheck(n, m, i+1, j, arr); //N
        neighborCheck(n, m, i-1, j, arr); //S
        neighborCheck(n, m, i, j+1, arr); //E
        neighborCheck(n, m, i, j-1, arr); //W
        neighborCheck(n, m, i+1, j+1, arr); //NE
        neighborCheck(n, m, i+1, j-1, arr); //NW
        neighborCheck(n, m, i-1, j+1, arr); //SE
        neighborCheck(n, m, i-1, j-1, arr); //SW
    }
}
```

This is the recursive function I used to 'mark' the neighbors 0 if they have been visited already. It should return a value of one at the main function and it increments from there.

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0

Number of Islands: 1
```

I tried placing this matrix inside but the output for the number of islands was only 1 and not 2.

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Here I tried to see if it did go through all the 1s and it did as it had replaced 0.
I even tried counting if it did read 1 at all by counting the number of 1s. So far, it had been producing the right results.

I don't know why it works for some matrices and not for some matrices.

Comment: You don't have a `return` value for the `else` part in the `neighborCheck()` function. Didn't your compiler warn you about that? Consider increasing the warning level.

Comment: Why does the function have a return type if you don't care about the return value?

Comment: Your range checks should not compare `>n` but `>=n`. Same for `m`. Also if you are looking at an element on an edge, e.g. in left most column, you skip all other sides as well, not only the side where you hit the edge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Any feedback yet? SO only works well if you respond to comments

Comment: hello yall! its been fixed now! much thanks!!!